# Innosetup - Make my program dir/shortcut in StartMenu + AllPrograms highlighted

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Shortcut is added in startmenu fine, just as the folder in start>AllPrograms with all icons

But how to make it highlighted like other recently installed programs do?

Comment: This is done automatically by the Microsoft Windows operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be highlighted when an icon/entry is newly created. If there was a manual way to trigger it, it could be abused.